# Squid only accepts connections to main IP

Tags: squid

So, I have multiple IP addresses in my server and I'd like Squid to "listen" them all.. like nginx for example uses 0.0.0.0. For some reason Squid only accepts connections to eth0 (other IPs are like eth0:1 eth0:2 etc). Any ideas how I'd be able to force Squid proxy to listen to all of those IP addresses I have.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the IPs are assigned and binded properly. You can edit your squid.conf  and add these lines anywhere in the top before your http_access lines.

```
acl ip1 myip 192.1.2.3
tcp_outgoing_address 192.1.2.3 ip1
acl ip2 myip 192.1.2.4
tcp_outgoing_address 192.1.2.4 ip2
acl ip3 myip 192.1.2.5
tcp_outgoing_address 192.1.2.5 ip3
```

And so on replacing with your IPs of course. You can also manipulate them so trafic coming in on IP sends out on another.